# Any good reason for DataContext="{Binding}"?

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

I found several times `DataContext="{Binding}"` in some xaml code I've inherited.

Am I missing something or is it really at best useless ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContext="{Binding}"` is useless.
But that doesn't mean that `{Binding}` is generally useless. For other properies it is perfectly good to use it.

Example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

This will bind the data context as the source of the items of the list box. Obviously, the data context should be some kind of list.

Comment: Thank you. Would you say it is more than useless, dangerous ? Doesn't that creates some kind of loop ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but here are some thoughts: If it would create a loop, it wouldn't work as there would be no exit condition. Therefore, I don't think it is dangerous.

Comment: There's no loop danger because bindings on DataContext use the inherited DataContext, not the local DataContext. If that weren't true you could never set any Binding on a DataContext that didn't explicitly specify a Source, which is obviously not the case.